# How to stop a running process during an wise installation based un-install?

Tags: installation, wise

when i unwsied a project,if the main program of the project is running, then the un-install del all the floders and files except the main program.

how can i do,when i unwise a project if the main program is running .i want alert a dialog "are you sure to un-install this project when xxx.exe is running".

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a batch file to kill the process, like:

```
taskkill /IM programname.exe
```

It will prompt the user are they sure or ask if they want to save changes. Use  `/F` to force the process to close.

Comment: first of all,thank you.  the use of taskkill i know,but i don't know how to  use it in wise installation script.    wise script has three types:1,setup;2,uninstal,3,rollback.  how can i do with wise intallation?